# What does the raised $^2$ stand for?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

What does the raised $2$ stand for? My first guess was: $4^2$ is $2\times 4=8$?

<sup>**Note**: Am not really good at math</sup>

Comment: Is that it? I guess a few operators are missing in your question.

Comment: OP that is called an exponent. it means you multiply the number by itself two times.

Comment: @lsp, yes. I never really understood what it actually represent, came across this site, and thought I'll ask.

Comment: @DonLarynx, so, `2x4`???

Comment: @blade19899 No, $4\times 4$. And $4^3$ is $4\times4\times4$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I get what the question about !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is called '**exponent**' or '**power**'.

Here $4^2$ means $4$ multiplied twice or in other words product of two $4's$. So:
$$4^2 = 4*4 = 16$$
Similarly $7^3$ means $7$ multiplied thrice or in other words product of three $7's$. So:
$$7^3 = 7*7*7 = 343$$
Since you are a starter, you can get more information about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Comment: Thanks, understand it better now!

Comment: I'm curious, why do you prefer $*$ to $\times$? In particular, is it purely an aesthetic choice?

Comment: Some use 'x', some use '.', some use '*'. Depends on who is comfortable with what. As far as I am concerned there is nothing wrong with using any of them.

Comment: Hmm ... $4 \times 4$ ... is it really $4$ multiplied by itself twice?  Actually, there is only one multiplication.

Comment: Overlooked ! Made a change now. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @GEdgar I suppose you could say $4^2$ is the product of two fours and $4^3$ is the product of three fours.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to put it.

Comment: You could also say that $^2$ stands for squared and $^3$ stands for cubed.

Comment: Yes. All those are mentioned in the link that I provided in my answer.